# How can I pass a float arg into a custom EL Function (jsp)?

Tags: function, tags, el, jsp-tags, taglib

***Error:** The method exchangeConversion(String, String, float) in the type MyExchangeClass is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, double)*

Code in jsp file, error with 15.4 and 15.4f as well, but if change function and TLD for double all works fine. Why is it taking 15.4 and 15.4f as if they were doubles?

```
...
From GBP to USD: ${ elfuncs:exchange("GBP", "USD", 15.4f) }
Otherwise: ${ elfuncs:exchange("GBP", "YEN", 15.4) }
```

Code  in TLD

```
  <function>
    <name>exchange</name>
    <function-class>mypackage.MyExchangeClass</function-class>
    <function-signature>float exchangeConversion(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, float)</function-signature>
  </function>
```

Code for the java class
    public class MyExchangeClass {

```
    public static float exchangeConversion(String from, String to, float amount) { 
        float calculatedAmount = 0.0f;

        /* Example implementation code: */
        if(from.equals("GBP") && to.equals("USD")) {
            calculatedAmount = amount*1.5f;
        }
        return calculatedAmount; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because that's specified as such in [EL specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/mrel/jsr245/index.html). Floating point literals are always interpreted as `double`.

> ## 1.3 Literals
>
> There are literals for boolean, integer, floating point, string, and null in an evalexpression.
>
> ...
>
> - Floating point - As defined by the `FloatingPointLiteral` construct in
>     Section 1.19.

> ## 1.19 Collected Syntax
>
> ...
>
> - The value of a `FloatingPointLiteral` ranges from `Double.MIN_VALUE` to `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

Just change `float` to `double` in your function.

Comment: So, for what you are saying. It is impossible to use float as arguments in a EL function, isn't it?

■ If A or B is a Float, Double, or String containing ., e, or E:
- If A or B is BigInteger, coerce both A and B to BigDecimal and apply
operator.
- Otherwise, coerce both A and B to Double and apply operator